# How to find out which unit depends on a known unit

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

Here's my problem:
`UnitA.pas` fails to be compiled as `UnitB.dcu` cannot be found.

So why don't I just add `UnitB.pas` to my project? - Because `UnitA.pas` shouldn't even be part of my project but is somehow contained by another unit. I want to find out, which unit that is.

How can I do that (I am using *Delphi XE4*)?

**Note:** I think there was some option in *Delphi 2007* to get the desired information in compilation log but I don't remember where it was...

Comment: Are you using search paths? They make life way more complicated.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, I am. And I don't want to change that for now.

Comment: Start procmon from sysinternals, compile, search for the first occurrence of UnitA in the output -> The previous occurrence should be you culprit. Other than that, I don't know of an easy way without reverting to (paying) third party tools.

Comment: You can try looking into DUDS tool (DelphiUnitDependencyScanner)

Comment: Thanks for your contributions. DUDS seems to be a very useful tool.

Comment: Because you use search paths you are running the gauntlet of getting unwanted units included. This is trivially avoided by not using search paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my workmates gave me the hint to just rename the units that should not be part of the project. Thus, I get an error in the depending unit. I continued with this until I found the unit reference I need to erase at almost root level.